# unity c# multiplayer game mirror - Call a method in script on every player's computers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

I am making a multiplayer online game,
Its like spider fight,
There are some methods in my player(spider) (attack,defence,legDead)
because of its a multiplayer game when a method called in my spider,
It should also effect my spider in the other computers
so i make a sending script;
I should make Cmd and Rpc method for every method(m1,m2,m3) but i don't want to do this,So is it possible to make a method and change it self even with its parameters like example code

I tried delegate and action but i think they are for only one type of methods

This code(player) is example by the way

```
using Mirror;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    void ChangableMethod;
    [Command]
    void Cmd()
    {
        Rpc();
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    void Rpc()
    {
        ChangableMethod();
    }

    //these methods have multiple parameters as example
    void m1(string s, string s2)
    {
        Debug.Log("m1");
    }
    void m2(string s,int s2)
    {
        Debug.Log("m2");

    }
    void m3(string s, bool b)
    {
        Debug.Log("m3");

    }
    void onmouseleftclick()
    {
        ChangableMethod = m1;
        Cmd();
    }
    void onmouserightclick()
    {
        ChangableMethod = m2;
        Cmd();
    }
    void onmousemiddleclick()
    {
        ChangableMethod = m3;
        Cmd();
    }
}
```

So when i call Cmd() it will send the method to every player

Comment: No of course not since `ChangableMethod = m1;` is only called locally on this client ... How should the others know if you don't tell them? You could however pass on a simple `enum` parameter and simply tell everyone which method to pass on or use e.g. the method name or whatever you want to as a key ...

Comment: And especially if these each need different parameters then no there is probably no clean way to call them all via one single RPC without having to cast at some point